# Why would /mnt/sdcard/ not appear?

Tags: adb, file-system, samsung-galaxy-tab-7-plus

Using ADB shell to view my Samsung Galaxy Tab 7+, I see a /mnt but no /mnt/sdcard/ where according to fable the photos taken by the camera should reside.   Why would the sdcard directory not be there?

Does the Tab need to be in some special mode or adb need some special incantation?

I'm doing this from an Ubuntu 11.something Linux machine.

UPDATE: got a new clue. Normally adb works only when the tablet is off, but has USB plugged in.  When I hold down the power button, the tablet starts up.  First there's a Samsung logo.  Eventually the splashy orange screen with the lock-circle thing appears.

During the Samsung logo phase, adb shell will show stuff in /mnt, including the lusted-for /mnt/sdcard.  But as soon as the orange lock screen appears (maybe slight sooner) adb is booted out, suddenly exiting to the xterm command line, and adb devices shows question marks instead of the device number.

So maybe all I need to do is find a way to make the tablet stay in Samsung-logo mode indefinitely, long enough for me to do my transfer.

Comment: Isn't it mounted at sdcard/external- sd? Can you do an ls-l in /mnt in /sdcard and in / (the root)?

Comment: Maybe it's just `/sdcard`

Comment: From what I read, external-sd is for actual physical sd cards.  I don't have one.  For the Galaxy Tab, /mnt/sdcard is a virtual card.  My understanding is probably faulty, though.

Comment: /sdcard is just a symlink to /mnt/sdcard, prolly as a convenience.

Comment: BTW, all this is just to get some photos over to my main desktop machine.  If I, a Linux expert, can't figure this out easily, how the heck to ordinary folk get their photos off their Galaxy Tabs?

Comment: It seems like the actual problem here has nothing to do with `/mnt/sdcard` not being there and everything to do with the fact that `adb` isn't seeing your device at all. The `??????` status usually implies you don't have udev rules set (or, generically, proper permissions for the usb device). I'd start with [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079361/390989) and see if that helps.

Comment: adb sees the device just fine. It just has to be under the right astrological conditions :P   Yup, I did that udev rule thing long ago.

Comment: ADB should be able to see the device when it's running normally.  If this were Windows I'd tell you to install the drivers :P

Comment: Not used to ADB, but giving a shot-in-the-dark: Could it be that as soon as the device is fully powered up, it sees the USB connection and enters UMS mode (i.e. no longer keeps the sdcard available locally, but rather handing it over to the PC to mount)?